# TypeError: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.ScalarMapContainer' object

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror, pickle, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run a reinforcement learning algorithm on robo-gym library environment using stble_baselines3. But I am receiving this error, but I don't know what is causing this error.

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import robo_gym
from robo_gym.wrappers.exception_handling import ExceptionHandling
from stable_baselines3 import DDPG

# specify the ip of the machine running the robot-server
target_machine_ip = '127.0.0.1' # or other xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

# initialize environment
env = gym.make('EndEffectorPositioningURSim-v0', ur_model='ur10',ip=target_machine_ip, gui=True)

env = ExceptionHandling(env)

model = DDPG("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=150)

model.save("DDPG_ur10e_sim")
```

I am receiving this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/addy/robo-gym-master/docs/examples/stable-baselines/td3_script.py in <cell line: 4>()
      38 #%%
      39 # choose and run appropriate algorithm provided by stable-baselines
      40 model = DDPG("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1)
----> 41 model.learn(total_timesteps=150)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ddpg/ddpg.py:130, in DDPG.learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, eval_env, eval_freq, n_eval_episodes, tb_log_name, eval_log_path, reset_num_timesteps)
    117 def learn(
    118     self,
    119     total_timesteps: int,
   (...)
    127     reset_num_timesteps: bool = True,
    128 ) -> OffPolicyAlgorithm:
--> 130     return super().learn(
    131         total_timesteps=total_timesteps,
    132         callback=callback,
    133         log_interval=log_interval,
    134         eval_env=eval_env,
    135         eval_freq=eval_freq,
    136         n_eval_episodes=n_eval_episodes,
    137         tb_log_name=tb_log_name,
    138         eval_log_path=eval_log_path,
    139         reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps,
...
--> 161     rv = reductor(4)
    162 else:
    163     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.ScalarMapContainer' object
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.